How to dynamically add or remove objects to nested array using react-hook-form?
I'm working on a project where I have a dynamic array of objects called variety, each containing another dynamic array called price. I'm using react-hook-form for form management, and I'm struggling to figure out how to add or remove objects to the price array when appending or removing objects to the variety array.
Here's the structure:
variety: [
  {
    colorId: "",
    image: [""],
    price: [
      {
        sizeId: "",
        price: 0,
        amount: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
],

I'm currently using the useFieldArray hook from react-hook-form to manage the variety array. However, I'm unsure how to handle the price array within each variety object dynamically.
Specifically, when I append a new object to the variety array using useFieldArray, I want to create a new price array for that object. Similarly, when I remove a variety object, I need to remove its corresponding price array.
How can I achieve this functionality using react-hook-form or any other approach?
I have already tried several methods, but I haven't been successful.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Edit 1:
Here is the code how I append a new object to variety array:
<Button variant="outline" type="button" onClick={() => {
        appendVarieties({
            colorId: "",
            image: [],
            price: [{ price: 0, sizeId: "", amount: 0 }],
        });
    }}>
    Add
</Button>


can you provide the code of how you append new object to variety array?

Added the code to the question
